# проблема с дизайном

Tags: android, material-design, design

Есть такое окно.Долго думаю над дизайном но ничего не приходит в голову. 
Desing guidelines от Google перечитал и не раз. Как построить макет по канонам материального дизайна в моем случае?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Материал дизайн тут не поможет.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 1):

Берите набор [Android-Iconics](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) - на мой взгляд лучшая реализация Material Design для Android - адаптированная под прогеров, а не для дизайнеров.

В числе прочих в этой либе есть [MeteoIcons](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics/tree/develop/meteocons-typeface-library) - порядка 200 иконок по тематике погоды и проч., типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизайн можно набрасывать через лейаут, например солнце можно так:

```
<com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsImageView
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    app:iiv_color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:iiv_icon="met_sun_inv" />
```

Comment: как устанавливать их в динамично в коде?картинка солнца подгружается с сервиса.

Comment: Конечно можно читайте мануал к либе - в общем надо `Drawable` переделывать в `IIcon` - примеров много - читайте, дерзайте.